# process input line by line with node CLI providing just an eval expression/callback to process each single line

Tags: node.js

I wonder about simple equivalent of `perl -ne 'some expression'` to be able to use node CLI possibly with `--eval '<some expression, func/arrow>'` and `--require some-line-by-line-enabler`. Is there any module making it possible or what can be approach to write one?

I've also found i.e. https://github.com/j-/require-cli and wonder if this may be the right way to go. I was trying it preparing some very basic module exposing forward of `readline.on('line', callback)` but consuming the stdin does not work just out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can eval scripts with Node from command line:

```
node -e "console.log('Hello!')"
```

Comment: I know this and I've already mentioned this in my question (as `-e` is same as `--eval`). The point is to provide just an expression which will be then applied to each line of pre-processed standard input (or optionally some file provided as an optional argument, yet this is just extra expectation)